# 14 year old abdominal training

Tags: abdominals, age, progress

When I was 13 I started training abs (sit ups), first I did 60 one day, 2 series of 30 and started from there. From there my progresion multiplied, started doing 120, 250, 500 and so on but I did this once or twice a week. Also I was a little underweight. (male)

Is it normal for abs training to progress that much?

When 14, I did my personal record of 1000 in 2 hours (not sure about the time). Right now I am 15 and would like to know if this was excesive, other than the common issue of hurting my lower back. My abs usually didn't hurt, only my back which hit the floor with a thin yoga mat too many times.

Was it excesive? Should I do it again?

Comment: I don't think doing as many situps as you can will help you achieve any goal other than doing lots of situps. What are you trying to get out of this?

Comment: I did it to get stronger abs and to exercise, to do something other than nothing.

Comment: If your goal is to just "do something", then you're doing that. If you want to see continued progress of whatever fitness or strength markers you're watching, you're gonna want a more thought out plan that implements progressive overload. Tbh I'd recommend getting involved in a sport if you just want to be active as opposed to just doing situps.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to clarify that the effectiveness of an exercise does not lie in the number of repetitions but in its precision.

If your abdominals did not hurt it is because they were not doing any (or very little) exercise.

Abdonimal exercise can be done daily but as with any muscle group it should always be done within a routine (time and repetitions, usually until failure) this means not "exercising" them at all hours of the day.

The amount of repetitions varies depending on the physical conditions of the individual but the exaggerated repetitions are often a sign of the lack of accuracy in the exercise.

The reasons why the low stretch may hurt may also be due to injuries that may not be directly related to exercise.

The recommendation is: Ask for help from a professional to review the technique of your exercises or look for videos or pages that explain step by step the methods of realization.

https://www.self.com/story/the-abs-exercises-you-should-skip-if-you-have-lower-back-pain

Comment: The muscles of the lower back are only capable of performing spinal extension, rotation, and lateral movements. It is physically impossible for them to "compensate" for the abdominals and perform spinal flexion or hip flexion instead.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I consider it to edit

Comment: I would argue that the blanket recommendation that exercises should usually be done to failure is a pretty bad one.

Comment: If you are looking for muscle growth and resistance, failure is necessary ... If you only want to maintain weight (in the case of women) you can spend all day on the treadmill if you like.

Comment: @ElenaByrne I disagree completely. Training to failure is definitely not the only way (or arguably the most effective way) of increasing strength or size. The offhand remark that maintaining weight is the case of women is both wrong and pretty sexist IMO. Also, I'd argue that spending a long time on the treadmill isn't particularly great for maintaining a set weight, regardless of gender.

Comment: @E.Aigle 1: About the exercise to failure is your opinion or do you support yourself with something?
2: Getting around the treadmill was just satire, I never put it down as a real recommendation. It seems that you did not understand it.  Let's leave it that way.

Comment: @ElenaByrne I think the burden of proof rests at your feet in recommending it. Training to failure can put individuals as unnecessary risk of injury especially for loaded movements. I'd be happy to reconsider if you could provide some evidence that training to failure is the best way to increase strength or size especially in the case of those just starting training as OP's question seems to suggest.

Comment: @E.Aigle In the world of fitness it is clear that there are no single rules. Here we give advice based on evidence and it is the user who must classify them according to their own physical capacities and training experience and specific goals.
A very common misconception is that physical exercise is simply physical exercise.
If someone can't (no matter how hard they try) train to failure or has joint problems, etc. Clearly this type of training is not for him ... otherwise in the world of bodybuilders or athletes like Crosffit.

Comment: @E.Aigle Any exercise, if not done correctly (until it fails or not) can cause injury.
That is why I wrote in the first answer that it is NECESSARY to have a training plan.
It's not about exercising all muscle groups until they fail on the fly.
Good physical exercise, even when led to failure with knowledge of one's abilities, with the right plan and movements, cannot result in harm.
This may not be worth much here, but I have seen people injure themselves with a single movement simply because they did not warm up properly and the ranges of movements are not correct.

Comment: @ElenaByrne I don't think the literature backs up a recommendation for regularly training to failure. I'd be happy to reconsider my stance if you could provide me with some reading material. You may like to read https://www.proquest.com/docview/213049778?pq-origsite=gscholar&fromopenview=true

Comment: @E.Aigle I think you don't understand me. My answer is simply based on the INDIVIDUAL's assessment of their own abilities and BASED on their exercise routine.
The exercise until failure, like the food CANNOT be unalterable, IT WILL VARY according to the physical, emotional, etc.
Research subject will ALWAYS vary, being research vs research.
If you want references, simply search wikipedia in the references section. 
Thanks and goodbye.